# How can I decrease the size of ArrayList to 2?

Tags: java

I must save two numbers in one data structure in java, but the order of these 2 number is important. That means, every time when I call these numbers; first number will be my Nucleus and second number will be my Satellite. I do not know which data type should I use, if I use ArrayList it will use so much memory, which I do not need. Because initial size of ArrayList is 10, but i need just 2. And if use HashSet, I do not have order.

```
ArrayList<int> array=new ArrayList<int>(2);
```

Comment: And waht is your question? The code you posted creates an ArrayList with a size of 2, which is the answer to the question in your title.

Comment: Are those values related in some way?

Comment: @f1sh, ArrayList by default has 10 size, you can't decrease it. But he wants something like that which can only occupy 2 units of data

Comment: I thought that this code is wrong, and i can not define an ArrayList with size of less than 10

Comment: Create enum and use, if it is possible

Comment: @Reddy of course you can. That's what the constructor with an ``int`` parameter is for. Of course then the size is not "decreased", the size was never anything else than 2.

Comment: The question is unclear.  Can you edit it and clean it up?  If you have found the answer to your question, post it here.

Comment: @VinitPrajapati enums make no sense here at all.

Answer (score 7):

I would actually lean more towards an `Object` based solution here; If anything for code readability.

```
public class Atom
{
    private int nucleus;
    private int satellite;

    public Atom(int nucleus, int satellite)
    {
         this.nucleus = nucleus;
         this.satellite = satellite;
    }
}
```

Referring to them as members of a class means you don't need to worry about the order, and you can store as many as you want in one collection.

```
List<Atom> atoms = new ArrayList<Atom>();
atoms.add(new Atom(4,1));

int nucleus = atoms.get(0).getNucleus();
// Assuming you've written your getter method.

int satellite = atoms.get(0).getSatellite();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simple Array[].

```
int[] data = new int[2];
int[0] = //nucleas
int[1] == //satellite.
```

But more importantly your question is not making any sense and the space/time for this requirement

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple array in java

```
int[] anArray;

// allocates memory for 2 integers
anArray = new int[2];
```

Comment: Java arrays are immutable. Also, OP can't have an ArrayList of primitives.

Answer (score 0):

List is preferable to use in those cases when you don't known the number of your elements. But in your case, You know that you only have 2 element then use araay instead

```
int[] array = new int[2];
```

and add value as

```
array[0] = <int_value>;
array[1] = <int_value>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just what you need to store two elements in ArrayList !

By passing 2 in ArrayList constructor you create backing array with length of 2. Next you can add 2 elements to it without resizing. But if you add third element to ArrayList then backing array will be resized. ArrayList is just a good wrapper of array so use it because it provides much more functionality than array.